# Tikzexternalize creates multiple copies of same figure

Tags: beamer, tikz-external

When compiling this document, tikzexternalize makes two copies of the small tikz figure.

Is it possible to only make one copy to speed up compilation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about using a box to save the picture and then just using it inside the `frame` environment?

Comment: I don't quite follow you, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Christian Feuersänger's answer is better ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\tikzsetnextfilename` to fix its name. The second compilation will detect that the figure is unchanged and re-use the existing pdf instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikzsetnextfilename{square}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```